# Blank website, restarting mysql fixes the problem

Tags: mysql, restart

Every two weeks or so my website becomes blank with a white page. When I restart mysql the website comes back.

I have a droplet on digital ocean with a lamp stack.

Any help on how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to see the log files.

Comment: Do your web server sends a completely empty HTTP response, or it sends a minimal HTML document without text content? Or it rejects, drops, or closes the TCP connection?

Answer (score 0):

For LAMP, I think we can say you get an empty page because MySQL stopped or crashed (Apache often gives empty pages with HTTP status 500 when PHP throws an uncaught error, like when `mysql_connect` fails).

You should investigate why is your MySQL stopping / crashing.

In one case, I didn't solve the issue itself, but I've worked around it with forcing mysql systemd service to restart automatically after crashing.

Add or Modify `Restart` line in `mysql.service` (located in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` or similar).

```
Restart=on-failure
```

Then run

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service mysql restart
```

and you should be fine.